# aes_cbc_128 encrypt/decrypt in c# visual studio

Tags: .net, encryption

Does anyone know what are the settings for salt, nrounds for encryption/decryption in .net c#? I need these information for openssl. I am tying to create an aes_128 with cbc encryption/decryption. In order to create the key I have to know these vaslues too: nrounds and salt. Thx

Comment: I think you set the IV in the crypto context. Isn't the number of rounds specified by key size?

Comment: that's why i'm asking..i don't know exactly. As I've understood the rounds, the salt, the key_data create a specific key used at encryption. This is how things work in openssl Linux:d. I would like to compare mu result with those on .net. And I would like to know what to set at the nrounds value, at salt in order to create the correct encription.

Comment: My results in linux:Ubuntu do not correspond with the results on .net. Why? Because I guess i did not set correctly the rounds. Help. Do you have any ideea of creating an encryption and decryption in linux using aes 128 and cbc and the key="test" without necesarely giving the nrounds and salt...in order to create the char [] key vector used at encryption? The IV is 0. Thx

Comment: @Rup is correct, the rounds for AES are not configurable, they are fixed by the standard. There is no salt in the AES algorithm. There are many many ways to use the numerous components in openssl. Unless you show some code how can we know what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for aes 128 bytes encryption with cbc and pkcs7

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#define AES_BLOCK_SIZE 128 //256
#include "base64.h"
#include "base64.cpp"
using namespace std;

int aes_init(unsigned char *key_data, int key_data_len, unsigned char *salt, EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e_ctx,
             EVP_CIPHER_CTX *d_ctx)
{
  int i, nrounds = 6;
  unsigned char key[16], iv[16];
    /*
   * Gen key & IV for AES 256 CBC mode. A SHA1 digest is used to hash the supplied key material.
   * nrounds is the number of times the we hash the material. More rounds are more secure but
   * slower.
   */
  i = EVP_BytesToKey(EVP_aes_128_cbc(), EVP_sha1(), salt, key_data, key_data_len, nrounds, key, iv);
  if (i != 16) {
    std::cout<<"Key size is: - should be 256 bits\n "<<i<<std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  for(int x = 0; x<16; ++x)
{
    std::cout<<"Key: and iv:  \n"<< key[x] <<std::endl;
    iv[x]=0;

}

  for(int x = 0; x<8; ++x)
 {std::cout<<"salt: \n"<< salt[x]<<std::endl;

salt[x]=0; }
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(e_ctx);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(e_ctx,7);
  EVP_EncryptInit_ex(e_ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(d_ctx);
  EVP_DecryptInit_ex(d_ctx, EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);

  return 0;
}

/*
 * Encrypt *len bytes of data
 * All data going in & out is considered binary (unsigned char[])
 */
unsigned char *aes_encrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e, unsigned char *plaintext, int *len)
{
    if (EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(e,7)!= 1) std::cout<<"no padding?"<<std::endl;


  /* max ciphertext len for a n bytes of plaintext is n + AES_BLOCK_SIZE -1 bytes */
  int c_len = *len + AES_BLOCK_SIZE - 1, f_len = 0;
  unsigned char *ciphertext = (unsigned char *)malloc(c_len);

  /* allows reusing of 'e' for multiple encryption cycles */
  if(!EVP_EncryptInit_ex(e, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)){
   std::cout<<"ERROR in EVP_EncryptInit_ex \n"<<std::endl;
    return NULL;
  }

  /* update ciphertext, c_len is filled with the length of ciphertext generated,
    *len is the size of plaintext in bytes */
  if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(e, ciphertext, &c_len, plaintext, *len)){
   std::cout<<"ERROR in EVP_EncryptUpdate \n"<<std::endl;
    return NULL;
  }

  /* update ciphertext with the final remaining bytes */
  if(!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(e, ciphertext+c_len, &f_len)){
   std::cout<<"ERROR in EVP_EncryptFinal_ex \n"<<std::endl;
    return NULL;
  }

  *len = c_len + f_len;
  return ciphertext;
}

/*
 * Decrypt *len bytes of ciphertext
 */
unsigned char *aes_decrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *e, unsigned char *ciphertext, int *len)
{
  /* plaintext will always be equal to or lesser than length of ciphertext*/
  int p_len = *len, f_len = 0;
  unsigned char *plaintext = (unsigned char *)malloc(p_len);

  if(!EVP_DecryptInit_ex(e, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)){
    std::cout<<"ERROR in EVP_DecryptInit_ex \n"<<std::endl;
    return NULL;
  }

  if(!EVP_DecryptUpdate(e, plaintext, &p_len, ciphertext, *len)){
    std::cout<<"ERROR in EVP_DecryptUpdate\n"<<std::endl;
    return NULL;
  }

  if(!EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(e, plaintext+p_len, &f_len)){
    std::cout<<"ERROR in EVP_DecryptFinal_ex\n"<<std::endl;
    return NULL;
  }

  *len = p_len + f_len;
  return plaintext;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  /* "opaque" encryption, decryption ctx structures that libcrypto uses to record
     status of enc/dec operations */
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX en, de;


  /* The salt paramter is used as a salt in the derivation: it should point to an 8 byte buffer or NULL if no salt is used. */
  //unsigned char salt[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
unsigned char salt[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
  unsigned char *key_data;
  int key_data_len, i;
  char *input[] = {"convert this string?",
                   NULL};

  /* the key_data is read from the argument list */
  //key_data = (unsigned char *)argv[1];
  //key_data_len = strlen(argv[1]);
  key_data = (unsigned char *) ("hello");
key_data_len = strlen("hello");
  /* gen key and iv. init the cipher ctx object */

  if (aes_init(key_data, key_data_len, salt, &en, &de)) {
  std::cout<<"Couldn't initialize AES cipher\n"<<std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  /* encrypt and decrypt each input string and compare with the original */
  for (i = 0; input[i]; i++) {
    char *plaintext;
    unsigned char *ciphertext;
    int olen, len;

    /* The enc/dec functions deal with binary data and not C strings. strlen() will
       return length of the string without counting the '\0' string marker. We always
       pass in the marker byte to the encrypt/decrypt functions so that after decryption
       we end up with a legal C string */
    olen = len = strlen(input[i])+1;

    ciphertext = aes_encrypt(&en, (unsigned char *)input[i], &len);
  //  plaintext = (char *)aes_decrypt(&de, ciphertext, &len);
/**/

      std::cout<<"OK: enc ok for: "<< ciphertext<<std::endl;

      std::string encoded_base = base64_encode(ciphertext,strlen((const char*)ciphertext));
      std::cout<<"the encr with base64: "<< encoded_base<<std::endl;

/* DECODING */

std::string decode = base64_decode(encoded_base);
std::cout <<"the decode woth base64: "<<decode<<std::endl;
unsigned char *ciphertext1= (unsigned char *)( decode.c_str() );
std::cout<<"chipertext1: "<<ciphertext1<<std::endl;
//reinterpret_cast< const unsigned char*>*/

char *plaintext1 = (char *)aes_decrypt(&de, ciphertext1, &len);


    if (strncmp(plaintext1, input[i], olen))
      std::cout<<"FAIL: enc/dec failed for: "<< input[i]<<std::endl;
    else
     {

//      std::cout<<"OK: dec ok for: "<< plaintext<<std::endl; // \"%s\"\n

     std::cout<<"the decr with base64: "<<plaintext1<<std::endl;
     }

    free(ciphertext);
    free(plaintext1);
  }

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&de);
  EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&en);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: compared wth the resut in .net - a simple encryption using same aes 128, chipper mode cbc, padding pkcs, the same key="hello" and the same iv set to 0 the result is different. WHY?! As I this the problem is the salt value and nrounds which in my code are set by the developer.